# MacBook Pro water damage

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, migration, damage, fluid.app

I spilt a cup of tea over my MacBook (MB) pro (gutted) and it promptly stopped working, wouldn't turn on and the fan wasn't turning over (I have done this before with wine). So I have received my new MB and I thought I'd try turning on the old one as I'm halfway through my Masters dissertation, so thought I would see if there was anyway of getting the information from the old MB onto the new one. So it has turned on but my tracking pad is not working. The pointer appears to be stuck in the top left hand corner. I've tried to do S+Command+? so the top bar highlights and managed to close down the programs. However what I need is a way to get into migration assistant to move the information onto my new MB. I appreciate the old MB is knackered and the insurance are coming to collect it this week. Just wondering if anyone knows of a way to click the migration assistant option?

Comment: Did you try plugging a mouse & external keyboard in?

Comment: You can activate cursor control with numeric keypad using opt-cmd-f5 or Mac with touch-id press quickly Touch ID 3 times

Comment: If you start Migration Assistant on the new Mac, you may be able to point it to the old one, without needing to do much on the old one. Or, Try connecting the old Mac in Target Disk mode, using a Thunderbolt cable.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most reliable way to transfer your data would be to use Target Disk Mode (https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mchlp1443/mac)

Connect your old MacBook to your new Mac with a Thunderbolt cable (alternatively you can use FireWire if your old Mac does not have Thunderbolt)

Then make sure your old MacBook is off and start it up while pressing and holding the T key.

Your old Mac will then be mounted like a regular external drive and you can either transfer your data by hand or use Migration Assistent (located in Applications > Utilities) on your new Mac.

---

Depending on the model of your old MacBook another option would be to take out it's drive and get an enclosure to connect it via USB.

---

Also: Please start making Backups. (Guide for Time Machine: https://support.apple.com/en-en/HT201250)